# how to remove and edit the values in JSON Array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a json array this way,

```
var simple = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   simple.push({ id: id, name: name, mobile: mobile });
}
```

And the values from this json array is as below,

```
[{id:1
  name:"Test"
  mobile:100},
{id:2
 name:"Test"
 mobile:200},
{id:3
 name:"Temp"
 mobile:300},
{id:4
 name:"Test"
 mobile:400},
{id:5
 name:"Temp"
 mobile:500}]
```

What i need to do is, I have to compare records in an json array based on "name" key.

While comparing, if `record1.name = record2.name` then i have to remove entire record1 and append "mobile" value of record1 with record2 , this way.

**This is the final output expected.**

```
[{id:1
  name:"Test"
  mobile:100,200,400},
{id:2
 name:"Temp"
 mobile:300,500}]
```

I tried removing this way. But not able to append the "mobile" key values with each other.

```
var removeItem = name;
alert('Array before removing the element = ' + simple);
simple = jQuery.grep(simple, 
                     function(value) { return value != removeItem; });
alert('Array before removing the element = ' + simple);
```

Can some one help me in this?

Thanks

**Edit
======**

I tried Answer#1=given by Ismail Kuruca given below,

Its working fine with the existing keys I.E, If added new keys with the below input,

```
var input = 
        [{
          id:1,
          name:"Test",
          ssn:1,
          mobile:100,
          address:"A"
        },
        {
         id:2,
         name:"Test1",
         ssn:2,
         mobile:200,
         address:"B"
        },
        {
         id:3,
         name:"Temp",
         ssn:3,
         mobile:300,
         address:"C"
        },
        {
         id:4,
         name:"Test2",
         ssn:4,
         mobile:400,
         address:"D"
        },
        {
         id:5,
         name:"Temp1",
         ssn:5,
         mobile:500,
         address:"E"
        }];
```

Its  is giving same value of "name" to all the newly added keys , as below, 
here "ssn" should be equal to 1, but it is returning "name" value : "test"

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Test","ssn":"Test","mobile":"100"},{"id":2,"name":"Test1","ssn":"Test1","mobile":"200"},{"id":3,"name":"Temp","ssn":"Temp","mobile":"300"},{"id":4,"name":"Test2","ssn":"Test2","mobile":"400"},{"id":5,"name":"Temp1","ssn":"Temp1","mobile":"500"}]
```

I tried this way,

```
//This part transforms your input to a map for each "name" attribute
        //Each key has a value of array of "mobile" 
        var intermediateObject = {};
        for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) { 
          if(typeof intermediateObject[input[i].name] == 'undefined') {
            intermediateObject[input[i].name] = [];
          }
          else if(typeof intermediateObject[input[i].ssn] == 'undefined') {
                intermediateObject[input[i].ssn] = [];
          }
          intermediateObject[input[i].name].push(input[i].mobile);
          intermediateObject[input[i].ssn].push(input[i].mobile); 
        }
        //Here the intermediate transformation is re-adjusted to look like your 
        //intended output format
        var outputObject = [];
        var index = 1;
        for(elem in intermediateObject ) {
          outputObject.push({
            id: index++,
            name: elem,
            ssn : elem,
            mobile: intermediateObject[elem].join(",")
          });
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(outputObject));
```

but it is not working.. Can some help me in this..

```
    Output should be,

    [{
      id:1,
      name:"Test",
      ssn:1,
      mobile:100,
      address:"A"
    },
    {
     id:2,
     name:"Test1",
     ssn:2,
     mobile:200,
     address:"B"
    },
    {
     id:3,
     name:"Temp",
     ssn:3,
     mobile:300,
     address:"C"
    },
    {
     id:4,
     name:"Test2",
     ssn:4,
     mobile:400,
     address:"D"
    },
    {
     id:5,
     name:"Temp1",
     ssn:5,
     mobile:500,
     address:"E"
    }];
```

Could you please help?

Comment: Can name have other values than "Test" or "Temp"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very crude example of transforming your input to desired output.

```
 var input = 
[{
      id:1,
      name:"Test",
      ssn:1,
      mobile:100,
      address:"A"
    },
    {
     id:2,
     name:"Test",
     ssn:1,
     mobile:200,
     address:"A"
    },
    {
     id:3,
     name:"Temp",
     ssn:3,
     mobile:300,
     address:"C"
    },
    {
     id:4,
     name:"Test2",
     ssn:4,
     mobile:400,
     address:"D"
    },
    {
     id:5,
     name:"Temp1",
     ssn:5,
     mobile:500,
     address:"E"
    }]; 

//This part transforms your input to a map for each "name" attribute
//Each key has a value of array of "mobile" 
var intermediateObject = {};
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) { 
  if(typeof intermediateObject[input[i].name] == 'undefined') {
    intermediateObject[input[i].name] = { ssn: null, address: null, content:[]};
  }
  intermediateObject[input[i].name].content.push(input[i].mobile); 
  intermediateObject[input[i].name].ssn = input[i].ssn; 
  intermediateObject[input[i].name].address= input[i].address; 
}


//Here the intermediate transformation is re-adjusted to look like your 
//intended output format
var outputObject = [];
var index = 1;

for(elem in intermediateObject ) {
  outputObject.push({
    id: index++,
    name: elem,
    ssn: intermediateObject[elem].ssn,
    address: intermediateObject[elem].address,
    mobile: intermediateObject[elem].content.join(",")
  });
}
```

**EDIT**: Modified the answer according to edit:
This is the output object:
[{"id":1,"name":"Test","ssn":1,"address":"A","mobile":"100,200"},{"id":2,"name":"Temp","ssn":3,"address":"C","mobile":"300"},{"id":3,"name":"Test2","ssn":4,"address":"D","mobile":"400"},{"id":4,"name":"Temp1","ssn":5,"address":"E","mobile":"500"}]

Comment: Do you want to merge additional fields also ? What happens when two objects with the same "name" have different "ssn" or "address"

Comment: Hi, I have edited my answer to fulfill your new requirements. Could you mark it as answer if the answer is suitable for your application ? thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I used a temporary object to figure out if a key is repeated or not. I then applied reduce to store objects with non-repeated keys and update the mobile array that they have with the mobile of the repeated element.

```
function final(arr) {
    var aux = {}, index = 0;
    return arr.reduce(function (memo, el) {
        var key = el.name,
            obj = aux[key];
        if (!obj) {
            aux[key] = {
                id: index++,
                name: key,
                mobile: el.mobile
            };
            memo = memo.concat(aux[key]);
        } else {
            obj.mobile += "," + el.mobile;
        }
        return memo;
    }, []);
}

console.log(final(arr));
```

You can check the result in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vm71qgmm/1/).

Hope it helps.